# Managing collections of shortcut-macros in collaboration projects

Tags: macros, collaboration

I write a lot of very similar documents, and thus make heavy use of shorthands such as

```
% Partial derivative
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{
\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}
}
```

As of now, I have a single file that contains each and every command I ever used, and i `\include` this file into almost every document. There are some catches though:

1. If i decide to change or generalize my shortcut, old compilations will break. Thus every project has its own copy of the file and if i do something in one file that i wish to use in another file, i have to make a copy. Explicit versioning files could possibly be a solution.
2. If I collaborate on a project, all hell breaks loose. Its just easier to make a new shortcut for that one use rather than to get used to an exisiting and possibly dynamic structure.
3. the same might affect some functions within matlab and python which generate dynamic parts, but that could be mitigated by requiring those to be 'standard latx'.

Earlier, I did use one single file which was within the Miktex path, but that becomes very cumbersome to manage.

Of course we use git and employ "unit tests", which only check if the file compiles.

Is there a better way of organizing and embedding shortcuts like this? I could imagine software engineers know this kind of problems...

I appreciate your input!

Addendum: Any ideas on how where to keep that file if its shared among users? As an individual project perhaps?

Comment: I voted to close as too broad. You've asked several tangentially-related questions. I have a good answer in mind for one or two of them, but not all of them. I'd suggest breaking the question into smaller individual questions and asking them separately.